# Blue screen of death in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

[image]

This happens when I'm downloading at high- speeds (500 kb/s or more), almost always within 3 minutes.

It never happens while I'm using the computer normally.

Comment: Can someone with enough rep edit it and change the link to an image? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've just found [this post](http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/windows-vista-windows-7-support/414695-windows-7-bsod.html) on the Microsoft tech support forum.

The answers seem to point to the network card, which would tie in with it crashing when you are downloading at high speeds. Have you got the latest drivers installed?